# RobotFramework - Importing test library "AutoItLibrary" failed: Initializing test library 'AutoItLibrary' with no arguments failed

Tags: robotframework, autoit

Can anyone support me this case?
I install Robotframework to a machine (win10 64b). The versions in my machine:
Python3.7.2 (32b)
pywin32==224 
 (32b)
robotframework==3.1.1 
robotframework-autoitlibrary==1.2.3 
robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1 
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1 
wxPython==4.0.4 (32b)

Import AutoItLibary, it is always red, Ride error log shows:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
Initializing test library 'AutoItLibrary' with no arguments failed: RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 167, in _get_instance
    return libcode(*self.positional_args, **dict(self.named_args))
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self._OutputDir  = self._get_log_dir()
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py", line 182, in _get_log_dir
    variables = BuiltIn().get_variables()
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 1293, in get_variables
    return self._variables.as_dict(decoration=is_falsy(no_decoration))
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 75, in _variables
    return self._namespace.variables
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 71, in _namespace
    return self._get_context().namespace
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 66, in _get_context
    raise RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarymanager.py", line 87, in _fetch_keywords
    return get_import_result(path, library_args)
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\libraryfetcher.py", line 24, in get_import_result
    lib = robotapi.TestLibrary(path, args)
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 54, in TestLibrary
    lib.create_handlers()
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 100, in create_handlers
    self._create_handlers(self.get_instance())
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 159, in get_instance
    self._libinst = self._get_instance(self._libcode)
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 169, in _get_instance
    self._raise_creating_instance_failed()
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 314, in _raise_creating_instance_failed
    % (self.name, args_text, msg, details))


20190326 17:31:22.876 [INFO]: Found Robot Framework version 3.1.1 from c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\robot.

20190326 17:31:22.876 [INFO]: Started RIDE 1.7.3.1 using python version 3.7.2 with wx version 4.0.4 in win32. ```
````

Comment: The error logs are different to that case. And the installed versions are different also. This case, all the versions are latest.

Comment: Have you gone through the solutions mentioned in this google groups post: [AutoITLibrary turn red in RIDE when installed successful.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/9krdDTlHNq0)

Comment: Yes, basically I walked through those workarounds before my post. However I think the error log in my case was different and the latest versions of all components may raise troubles here. <br>
PS: I am trying installing the latest version because it says python2.7 will not be supported in near future.

Comment: Hello, today I fixed the error. I uninstall all components. Then using CCleaner clean up the regedit and other clean. Then reinstall all by default, using pip only. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the robotframework-autoitlibrary.

The way I found to fix and use autoit in RF was to uninstall the "robotframework-autoitlibrary" and install the "autoitlibrary" found here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/ with python setup.py install as Admin.

Initializing error is now gone.

Comment: Hello, today I fixed the error. I uninstall all components. Then using CCleaner clean up the regedit and other clean. Then reinstall all by default, using pip only. It works now.

Answer (score -3):

AutoItLibrary is not built in with robot framework you need to import the library.

```
pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
```

Comment: That command was used. And as I wrote, the autoitlibrary==1.2.3 .

Comment: Hello, today I fixed the error. I uninstall all components. Then using CCleaner clean up the regedit and other clean. Then reinstall all by default, using pip only. It works now.